# Remove/ Replace span of Specific String from the sentence

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the span tag from string of sentence .Is it possible .?

My Input is as below :

```
divData = Welcome Hello <span> World </Span> ! Looking forward the great <span>things</span>.
```

Output I am looking for :

```
divData = Welcome Hello World ! Looking forward the great <span>things</span>.
```

what I have tried is :

```
  str = divData.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,"");
```

But above one is replacing all the span of all sentence.

Comment: Why aren't you also removing the other span? Is it just the first one you want removed?

Comment: Thank Andy for your reply !! I just want to remove first span only. or like span of specific string only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
str = divData.replace(/<span[^>]*>/,"");
str = str.replace(/<\/?Span[^>]*>/,"");
```

(Removed 'g' flag)
'g' means global, it will replace everything in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `replace` here in non global mode, which will target the first span tag only:

```js
divData = "Welcome Hello <span> World </span> ! Looking forward the great <span>things</span>.";
divData = divData.replace(/<span>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/span>/, "$1");
console.log(divData);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the quick answer, yes it will remove first span only but what i need is removing for specific string.. suppose i am entering an input as string "things", then it should not remove the "world" span, it should only remove the "things" span

Comment: Please respond to the comments under your question.